# Changing pandas column value using like

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Within my dataframe, df, I would like to divide the Qty column by 10 if in the Description column it contains the substring 'BC'

[image]

In the past I have only had to deal with the case if the cell equals a value like in the below, so am not sure how to tackle this one

```
df.loc[df.Description == 'ABC', 'Qty'] = df.Qty/10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.contains`:

```
df.loc[df.Description.str.contains('BC'), 'Qty'] /= 10
```